# I'm using a wordpress template and there is a option to add property. But there are some fields which I don't require

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a project where I'm supposed to make a woocommerce site. 
I've used HomeSweet wp theme. But while adding property, the defined fields are very much than clients expectations. Is it possible to remove some of the fields or else to rename those with other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a premium wordpress theme, authors are keeping all the possibilities in mind to fulfill the requirements of all the clients, if u want to edit some of the fields, you can easily edit or remove through their specific php files,for example- properties.php

If not able to, then hire a developer who can make a custom theme from scratch as per your requirements. getting a theme as per the need and from scratch is a better idea as they won't have unnecessary bulky files and your website will score good on SEO and Google page insights.